# Error while installing primavera web service. Could not find the main class the program will exit

Tags: oracle, web-services, ant, weblogic, primavera

I am trying to install  Primavera web services so i can deploy them on oracle Weblogic server(10.3) but its showing the error message box:

> could not find the main class the program will exit.

JVM launcher displays this message box.
I have installed all the prerequisites (Java 1.7,Apache ant, Apache cxf 2.2.2,Jackrabit etc.) 
and also set the environment variables for both JAVA_HOME and CXF_HOME.
please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your Primavera version? Always include the version details. Did you check the web-services which home is it referring to? `JAVA_HOME` or `SUN`?

Comment: Primiavera p6 R15.2 64bit  and how can i check the web services referring home? Because I have not been able to install web services

Comment: Does it even say the name of the main class?

Comment: @Rao No it does not.